# SQL Server : get the 2 most recent invoices by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a query where we would like to return the 2 most recent by date records.

For example:

```
Code    Item     Date                   Price1      Price2
--------------------------------------------------------------
0000    10000   2020-04-10 00:00:00.000 55.000000   55.000000
0000    10000   2020-04-04 00:00:00.000 55.000000   55.000000
0000    10000   2020-03-07 00:00:00.000 55.000000   55.000000
0000    10000   2020-03-04 00:00:00.000 55.000000   55.000000
0000    10000   2020-02-04 00:00:00.000 48.000000   48.000000
```

The SQL syntax written so far, returns and orders the records by `DESC`, via an inner join of the 2 tables, but we need to get the 2 most recent records, having as parameter the date and the record entry.

```
SELECT 
    t0.Code, t1.Item, t0.Date, 
    t1.Price AS price1, t1.Price AS price2
FROM
    dbo.INV AS t0 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.INV1 AS t1 ON t0.RecEntry = t1.RecEntry
WHERE  
    (t1.Price <> 0) 
ORDER BY 
    t1.Date DESC
```

Using `SELECT TOP * 2` for example, after the order by doesn't work, probably due to the syntax, as we never wrote a similar query before.

Any hints are appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried SELECT TOP 2 t0.Code, t1.Item, t0.Date, t1.Price AS price1, t1.Price AS price2
FROM     dbo.INV AS t0 INNER JOIN
                  dbo.INV1 AS t1 ON t0.RecEntry = t1.RecEntry
WHERE  (t1.Price <> 0) ORDER BY t1.Date DESC

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: So where is your "parameter"? What does "doesn't work" actually mean and how did you make that determination? Your query self-joins on the column RecEntry but that is not included in your sample and there is no obvious reason for the join. Mind reading does not work over the internet - you need to provide more and better detail.

Comment: If you `order by date DESC` (descending) the limit 2  will give the the 2 biggest values, which for a date is the 2 most recent.

Comment: @SMor Please, allow me to provide more input: We are trying to get the 2 more recent by date records, and show the prices to 2 different columns (price1 column and price2 column). The input criteria is the record entry, for example "where t1.RecEntry = 5"
Hope that helps to clear out the requirements.

Comment: You are showing the Date in your return from t0, but ordering by the Date in t1. Is that on purpose? If so, maybe move your main query into a CTE and try to work in  a row numbering or rank value that orders by the other T1 date value. You'll have to figure out if you need to include a PARTITION with it...can't tell from what you have if it would be needed (i.e. do you need 2 most recent per different Item, or different Code). ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY t1.Date DESC) as DateRank, then select from the CTE where DateRank <= 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT top 2  
    t0.Code, t1.Item, t0.Date, 
    t1.Price AS price1, t1.Price AS price2
FROM
    dbo.INV  t0 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.INV1 t1 ON t0.RecEntry = t1.RecEntry
WHERE  
    (t1.Price <> 0) 
ORDER BY 
    t1.Date DESC
```